# Trouble setting up nice urls with php / .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

i have a problem setting up nice urls on my php site and hope you guys can help me out here.

The actual url loooks like this right now:
http://www.domain.com/product.php?op=showm&name=the-slug&id=id

I want it to look like this:
http://www.domain.com/products/the-slug/id or even better without the id.

Any help appreciated, thanks so much!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried solving this rewrite problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is help from a `mod rewrite` generator. Here's a good one. http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Here is what you can try adding to your `.htaccess` file, too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /product.php?op=showm&name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

**The original URL:** http://www.domain.com/product.php?op=showm&name=the-slug&id=id

**The rewritten URL:** http://www.domain.com/products/the-slug/id